# Issue with ports.ubuntu.com

Tags: apt

Starting from Ubuntu desktop image downloaded from Radxa site:

http://dl.radxa.com/rock/images/ubuntu/radxa_rock_ubuntu_desktop_140318_update.zip

I installed linaro on my radxa. I didn't change the sources.

I'm trying to install apps through Synaptics and apt-get install.
It seems the source ports.ubuntu.com is down or wrong for some libraries (armhf especially). I am receiving a 404 error message telling it is not possible to fetch the files. So, I'm not able to install anything. Some weeks ago it was working fine....

Please find the error log:

```
rock@radxa:~$ sudo apt-get update

Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg

Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg

Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release

Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com raring Release

Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources/DiffIndex

Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources

Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources/DiffIndex

Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main armhf Packages

Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/main armhf Packages/DiffIndex

Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main/debug armhf Packages

Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/universe armhf Packages/DiffIndex

Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en

Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main/debug Translation-en

Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en

Ign http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en

Err http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

Err http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

Err http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/main armhf Packages
 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

Err http://ports.ubuntu.com raring/universe armhf Packages
 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring/main/source   /Sources 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring/main/binary-armhf/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/raring/universe/binary-armhf/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.140 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
rock@radxa:~$
```

I obtain similar error if I try to install something, with sudo apt-get install vlc for example
What's the issue? the same image was working 1 week ago.

Comment: Ubuntu Raring (13.04) has reached End-Of-Life, and the packages have/are being removed form the official Ubuntu repos. Please upgrade to Trusty.